# Where do rack application output goes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, puma, grape-api

I have a rack application running in the following way:

```
$: << File.expand_path("../lib",__FILE__)

require '<my_app>/api'

STATIC_DIR = File.expand_path("../public/",__FILE__)

run Rack::Cascade.new [<my_app>::API, Rack::Directory.new(STATIC_DIR)]
```

and it runs with puma like this:

```
exec rackup -s Puma -p $PORT
```

My app is some kind of a simple API written with ruby's grape rest api.
my question is, where do all the application output goes ? I mean, all the GET requests for example, i am pretty new to this, and was not able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
exec rackup -s Puma -p $PORT >> $LOG
```